# Is there any automatic solution to remove comments and console.log from solidity files?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

still learning Solidity and all ecosystem around it and I still thinking about the best way how to perform deployment.

I have my solidity contracts (using HardHat suite) where I have some console.log statements as same as comments.

But I believe it would be better to clean all comments and console.log before deploying to production.

So what I would like to do is:

- remove all console.logs
- remove all comments
- run prettier to re-format code

And then, tell HardHat to compile & deploy this modified contracts (for example exported to contracts.prod) and deploy it to production.

Are there any tools for that? Or should I write some scripts by myself by using regex/prettier manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is Hardhat plugin called [hardhat-log-remover](https://github.com/ItsNickBarry/hardhat-log-remover) that can do this for you. You just add it as a plugin in your Hardhat config, and then you can run it from the terminal like this:

```sh
$ yarn run hardhat remove-logs
```

Comment: thanks, I will check it!

Comment: One more thanks for the reply. It seems that hardhat-preprocessor fits even more to my use case.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth reviewing the work of hardhat-log-remover.
For example:

```
if (condition) console.log('...');
action;
```

will be converted to:

```
if (condition) action;
```

which is wrong

If we use {}:

```
if (condition) { console.log('...'); }
```

will be converted to

```
if (condition) { }
```

which is redundant